# can a hole exist on a horizontal asymptote and it still be considered crossing

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

There is a horizontal asymptote (HA). I know they can be crossed. Let's say y=1 at the HA.

But I want to know if it's crossed at any point by setting the function to equal to 1 and solving for x.

But then I get a hole on the HA. Is it still considered crossing if the function continues past the HA. Or what about if the hole is an endpoint? Then it wouldn't be considered crossing the HA?

Answer (score 1):

"Crossing point" is not a term that I think has been very rigorously defined in this question, so this may be a semantic issue, but I would say no it's not considered a crossing point if there is a hole there.

After all, if you were looking for zeros of a rational function and you found that the only possible place for a zero is at $x = 1$, but there was also a hole at $x = 1$, you would say that the function has no zeros. In other words, you would say it doesn't cross the $x$-axis at $x = 1$.